# iDangero.us Pagination option after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm using idangero.us swiper as an image slider and I have the option to enable the pagination and keep track of what image I'm on. The page is loaded via ajax. Here's my script,

```
$('#a1').bind('pageshow', function(e){

 var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{

    pagination: '.pagination',  
    grabCursor: true,
    paginationClickable: true  })

});
```

Now when the page is loaded in the DOM, I get the swiper's effects and the pagination is visible, but it doesn't track my images unless I navigate away then go back. Any idea on why this is?

Comment: Was `#a1` page dynamically created?

Comment: #a1 is an external html file that I load through jquery mobile's ajax. Its stripped down of all head and body tags and is just divs

Comment: try `$(document).on('pageshow, '#a1', function () {` and maybe you need to `$('#a1').trigger('pagecreate');` after loading it via ajax.

Comment: It tracks it when I click on the markers but still not when I'm swiping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, well now I feel like an idiot. Nothing wrong with how it was calling the swiper, it was bad html. My structure was messed up and was affecting how the swiper would work.